# Hide XML documentation

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, plugins, visual-studio-extensions, xml-documentation

I hate comments of any kind, esp. large chunks of XML documentation that are mixed up with code. It makes for a very difficult reading of code.

Is there a tool that can hide the XML documentation in a project?

Answer (score 1):

[Atomineer Pro Documentation](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) extension allows you to hide the documentation using outlining too. However it is paid application.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that I could collapse the code to only show the definitions.

If you know of a better way, I'd love to hear.

[image]